# localhost:3030 merging 2

Tags: javascript, node.js

I currently have a js script to host a localhost and another javascript for my array. How come when I do localhost:3030/api/cars, im not getting a list of arrays? 
Here are my codes:

```
'use strict'

const express = require('express')

const app = express()

const cars = require('./cars.js');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello from Express.')
})

app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    const payload = {
        message: 'Hello from Express',
        cars: cars
    }
    res.send({
        data: payload
    })
})

app.get('/api/cars', (request, response) => {
    response.send({data: cars})
  })

app.listen(3030, err => {
    if (err) {
        return console.log('Something bad happened', err)
    }
    console.log(`The server is listening on port 3030 ...`)
})
```

Here is my javascript with an array.

```
const cars = [{
        id: 1,
        make: 'Tesla',
        model: 'S',
        colour: 'Black'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        make: 'Tesla',
        model: '3',
        colour: 'Red'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        make: 'Tesla',
        model: 'X',
        colour: 'Silver'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        make: 'Tesla',
        model: 'Y',
        colour: 'Chestnut Brown'
    }
]
```

How can I fix my first javascript file so that localhost:3030/api/cars will show the list of cars?

Answer (score 0):

when you write `const cars = require('./cars.js');` in your js file, you actually call the cars.js file, not the `cars` array. Edit your cars.js file this way if you want to import the `cars` array.

```
const cars = [{
    id: 1,
    make: 'Tesla',
    model: 'S',
    colour: 'Black'
},
{
    id: 2,
    make: 'Tesla',
    model: '3',
    colour: 'Red'
},
{
    id: 3,
    make: 'Tesla',
    model: 'X',
    colour: 'Silver'
},
{
    id: 4,
    make: 'Tesla',
    model: 'Y',
    colour: 'Chestnut Brown'
}
]

module.exports = cars;
```

This way your cars.js file exports the array you want.